# react native write to sms without sending it

Tags: android, ios, react-native, sms

I want to write a app to backup and restore sms.

I know I can read sms using react-native, but how can I write the sms to the phone without actually sending it using react-native?

Thanks

Comment: You can't read or write SMS on iOS. You can present a pre-filled text message for the user to edit and send

Comment: how about in Android?

Comment: What have you done already? Show us some code that is not working or partially working. This is too broad of a question and you need to do your research first.